# How does shmget allocate memory? Cannot access with linear addressing (Address Boundary error)

Tags: c, pointers, shared-memory, allocation

In the following example, I'm trying to use `shmget` to allocate memory for *one integer, and 10 `foo` structs* and trying to access them linearly. However, it errors out with an "Address Boundary error".

For a MacOS system (but should be the same on Linux), I tried to allocate the exact amount of memory the two data structures should have taken and tried to byte address them linearly.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

typedef struct {
  int f1;
  int f2;
} foo;

int main() {
  // Size of memory. Consider, int size to be 4. (4 + 8 * 10 = 84 bytes)
  const int shmsz = sizeof(int) + sizeof(foo) * 10; 

  // Create shared mem id.
  const int shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, shmsz, 0666);
  if (shmid < 0) {
    perror("shmget failed.");
    return 1;
  }

  // Pointer to the shared memory. Cast as char* for byte addressing.
  char* shmemPtr = (char*) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
  if (*shmemPtr == -1) {
    perror("shmat failed.");
    return 1;
  }

  // The integer should point to the first 4 bytes. This is the same as
  // the address pointed to by shmemPtr itself.
  int* iPtr = (int*) shmemPtr[0];

  // The 80 bytes for the 10 foos range from index 4 -> 83
  foo* fPtr = (foo*) ((void*) shmemPtr[sizeof(int)]);

  printf("i: %p\n", iPtr); // why is this 0x0 ?
  printf("x: %p\n", fPtr); // why is this 0x0 ?

  *iPtr = 0; // <-- This dereference crashes, probably since the address of iPtr is 0x0
}
```

After allocating the memory and receiving a pointer to it via `shmat`, any pointers I try to create to the allocated memory is `0x0` and any derefences will (rightfully) crash the program. I expected the `int*` and `foo*` to be valid pointers to shared memory.

I'm just dabbling with some systems stuff with C/C++ so forgive me if I'm trivially missing anything here.

Comment: This is wrong: `int* iPtr = (int*) shmemPtr[0];`. `shmemPtr` is a pointer to `char`, so `shmemPtr[0]` is a `char`. You should not be converting a `char` to a pointer. You may want `int *iPtr = (int *) shmemPtr;` or `int *iPtr = (int *) &shmemPtr[0];`. Your compiler should have warned you about this. If it did not, add `-Wall` to your compiler switches.

Comment: Similarly, `foo* fPtr = (foo*) ((void*) shmemPtr[sizeof(int)]);` should be `foo *fPtr = (foo *) &shmemPtr[sizeof(int)];`.

Comment: This is wrong: `*shmemPtr == -1`. If `shmat` fails, it returns a pointer that is −1 in its "value". It does not point to a memory location containing −1. Compare it with `shmemPtr == (char *) -1`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That did the job. I figured it was something to do with me not referencing pointers right. Thanks for the tip about the compiler flag!

Comment: In `printf("x: %p\n", xPtr);`, `xPtr` is not declared. This means you posted code in the question that is different from the code you compiled (including different because it omits something). (Your posted code also omits includes you must have, such as `#include <sys/shm.h>`.) When you ask questions about what is wrong with code, you should post **exact** code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: When you turn on warnings, the compiler will complain about `printf("i: %p\n", iPtr);`. When printing a pointer with `%p`, convert it to `void *`: `printf("i: %p\n", (void *) iPtr);`.

Comment: Tag questions like this with the language you are compiling in, not both C and C++. Which are you using?

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  The posted code causes the compiler (`gcc`) to output 5 warnings, all of what are serious warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` ).  Other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* shmemPtr = (char*) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
```

You've got now a pointer to your shared memory block. It is a `char *`, pointing to the start of the block. So far, so good.

```
int* iPtr = (int*) shmemPtr[0];
```

Since `shmemPtr` is a `char *`, `shmemPtr[0]` is its first byte. The above, inexplicably, converts a single byte into an `int *`. This makes no sense, of course.

You obviously meant to reinterpret `shmemPtr` as a pointer to your `int`, so you can `*iPtr` in order to read the first `int` that you expect to be in your shared memory block. If so, this should be:

```
int* iPtr = (int*) shmemPtr;
```

That's for C. If you're using C++, you can also help your compiler help you from shooting yourself in the foot:

```
int* iPtr = reinterpret_cast<int *>(shmemPtr);
```

Forging ahead, we come next to:

```
foo* fPtr = (foo*) ((void*) shmemPtr[sizeof(int)]);
```

Congratulations. `shmemPtr[sizeof(int)]` is, apparently, `shmemPtr[4]`, or the fifth byte in your shared memory block; and you just dragged your compiler, kicking and screaming, into converting that single byte into a `void *`, first, then into a `foo *`.

Obviously, you meant to compute the ***address*** of that byte, and then reinterpret it.

```
foo* fPtr = (foo *)(shmemPtr + sizeof(int));   /* C default */

foo* fPtr = reinterpret_cast<foo *>(shmemPtr + sizeof(int)); /* Preferred in C++ */
```

This still may or may not be 100% correct, due to platform-specific alignment issues. But this will be a good first start.

Comment: Thanks. If it's not going to be aligned like this always, then how does one go about doing what I'm trying in a portable way? Do I individually create shared pieces of memory for each of the components?

Comment: The C++ tag has just been removed — and there's some justification for doing so (no C++-specific code).  But, unfortunately, that makes `reinterpret_cast` inappropriate.  I'm in two minds about whether to reinstate the C++ tag or to suggest you remove the C++-only suggestions from your answer.  Do you have a preference?

Comment: Both C and C++ can be covered here. As far as alignment goes, in simple situations like these, where performance is not a concern, after computing the address the usual approach is to simply `memcpy` it into a separately-declared `struct`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I have had to search for answers specific to C or to C++ in the past. Maybe you think you are helping by offering answers to both/either, but cluttering search results has a cost. It can be a nuisance to have to look through too many answers to discard the inapplicable ones.